# Как с двух массивов сделать обьект с новыми свойствами?

Tags: javascript

Есть, к примеру, такой массив объектов

```js
items = [
    {
      id: "1",
      name: "тест1",
      parents_names: ["Московская", "Орехово-Зуевский"],
      parents_levels: [1, 3]
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      name: "Тест2",
      parents_names: ["Карелия", "Прионежский", "Центральный"],
      parents_levels: [1, 3, 7]
    },
    {
      id: "3",
      name: "Тест3",
      parents_names: ["Санкт-Питер"],
      parents_levels: [1]
    },
];
```

В `parents_levels` у нас находится инфа о том, что именно пришло в `parents_names`.
то есть к примеру 1 = регион, 3 = район, 7= улица и тому подобное.

мне на выходе нужно получить новый объект такого формата

```js
newItems = [
    {
      id: "1",
      name: "тест1",
      region: "Московская",
      area: "Орехово-Зуевский"
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      name: "тест2",
      region: "Московская",
      area: "Орехово-Зуевский",
      street: "Центральный"
    },
    {
      id: "3",
      name: "тест3",
      region: "Санкт-Питер",
    }
    ];
```

Подскажите как это реализовать с использованием js?

Comment: У вас есть собственные наработки по задаче? "Домашние задания надо выполнять самостоятельно. Если у вас возник вопрос по домашнему заданию, не просите его сделать за вас. Задайте конкретный вопрос о проблеме, которую вы не можете решить. Программирование — это то, в чём надо разбираться самому, либо не заниматься им вовсе. Если для вас программирование — лишний предмет в учебной программе, есть сайты и люди на этих сайтах, выполняющие задания за материальное вознаграждение. Здесь предлагать выполнить работу за вас и наоборот — моветон."

Comment: Извините, я делал свою реализацию, но она у меня не работала. Я решил не тратить времени на описание своей реализации, а написать четко по дело. И я не просил полностью сделать задание за меня, а лишь попросил в помощь в реализации, что не означает полностью решить задание за меня.

Comment: Вам следовало в вопросе привести свой код. Возможно ваша реализация потребовала небольшой корректировки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно реализовать, например, следующим образом.

```js
items = [
    { id: "1", name: "тест1", parents_names: ["Московская", "Орехово-Зуевский"], parents_levels: [1, 3] },
    { id: "2", name: "Тест2", parents_names: ["Карелия", "Прионежский", "Центральный"], parents_levels: [1, 3, 7] },
    { id: "3", name: "Тест3", parents_names: ["Санкт-Питер"], parents_levels: [1] },
];

var levels = { 1: "region", 3: "area", 7: "street" };

var result = items.map(function(v){
       var result = { id: v.id, name: v.name };
       v.parents_levels.forEach( function(l, i){
            result[ levels[l] ] = v.parents_names[i];
       })
       
       return result; 
    });
    
console.log(result)    ;
```

хотя вероятно, можно и поэлегантнее решение придумать. тут, так сказать "в лоб"

---

вариант с `reduce()`:

```js
items = [
    { id: "1", name: "тест1", parents_names: ["Московская", "Орехово-Зуевский"], parents_levels: [1, 3] },
    { id: "2", name: "Тест2", parents_names: ["Карелия", "Прионежский", "Центральный"], parents_levels: [1, 3, 7] },
    { id: "3", name: "Тест3", parents_names: ["Санкт-Питер"], parents_levels: [1] },
];

var levels = { 1: "region", 3: "area", 7: "street" };



var result = items.map( v =>      
               v.parents_levels
                .reduce( 
                   (acc, l, i) => ( acc[ levels[l] ] = v.parents_names[i],  acc ),
                   { id: v.id, name: v.name }
                )     
             );

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let items = [{
    id: "1",
    name: "тест1",
    parents_names: ["Московская", "Орехово-Зуевский"],
    parents_levels: [1, 3]
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    name: "Тест2",
    parents_names: ["Карелия", "Прионежский", "Центральный"],
    parents_levels: [1, 3, 7]
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    name: "Тест3",
    parents_names: ["Санкт-Питер"],
    parents_levels: [1]
  },
];

console.log(items);

for (let item of items) {
  for (let i = 0; i < item.parents_levels.length; i++) {
    switch (item.parents_levels[i]) {
      case 1:
        item.region = item.parents_names[i];
        break;
      case 3:
        item.area = item.parents_names[i];
        break;
      case 7:
        item.street = item.parents_names[i];
        break;
    }
  }
  delete item.parents_names;
  delete item.parents_levels;
}

console.log(items);
```